# Does there exist a $GL(V)$-invariant element which is dependent on the choice of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

The motivating example is the element $C = \sum b_i \otimes b_i^*$, where $b_i$ a basis of some finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and $b_i^*$ its dual basis.
This element is independent of the choice of basis, I think because if $c_i$ were some other basis then there would be an invertible transformation $ g \in GL(V)$ between the two bases, however $C$ is assumed to be $GL(V)$ invariant, so this gives the same element.

But if this reasoning is correct, then it seems that all $GL(V)$-invariants are independent of basis choice, which seems both plausible but maybe wrong. What kind of counterexample is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "dependent on the choice of basis." The simplest definition is "not $GL(V)$-invariant," in which case the answer is no by definition.

On the other hand, your example has the funny property that it's unclear whether there's a way to define $\sum b_i \otimes b_i^{\ast} \in V \otimes V^{\ast}$ in a way that doesn't require picking a basis first. Here is one such definition: there's a natural map

$$V \otimes V^{\ast} \to \text{End}(V)$$

and $V$ is finite-dimensional iff this map is an isomorphism (in general its image is the space of finite rank operators). So when $V$ is finite-dimensional we can talk about the preimage of $\text{id}_V \in \text{End}(V)$ under this map, which turns out to be $\sum b_i \otimes b_i^{\ast}$. But this is a definition that doesn't require a choice of basis (except insofar as bases may be required to define what "finite-dimensional" means and to prove facts like the above about finite-dimensional vector spaces).

Comment: What other definitions of "dependent on choice of basis" can there be? If we take it literally as "changing basis changes the element", is it clear that this is equivalent to "being not $GL(V)$-invariant"?

Comment: @Qizard: yes, those are equivalent. I mean you might have meant “I don’t know how to write this element down without picking a basis, even though it ends up independent of that choice.”